# Fastest Drawing Possible, Pen Assignment and if statement

Tags: c#, performance, graphics, pen

Which is the most efficient & which is (subjectively) the most readable? (Another developer wrote the second option and I want to be sure I have a good reason for changing it to match the first option below)

```
Pen pen = Pens.Red;
if (highlight)
    pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3.0f);
```

or

```
Pen pen;
if (highlight)
    pen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3.0f);
else
    pen = Pens.Red;
```

I know that it makes a marginal difference, but I have a draw algorithm that needs to be literally as fast as possible! so every little bit helps. And no, using another language to handle the drawing is not an option at this point.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think `Pen pen = (highlight) ? new Pen(Color.Red, 3.0f) : Pens.Red;` is most readable. If you're that concerned with performance, you should be profiling your code.

Comment: @John It literally means "run a profiler on your code". What does a profiler do? It provides a "profile" (go figure) of which parts of your code take the most time (use the most memory/open the most handles/etc.) That information can then be used to make decisions about how to improve deficiencies in your code. In this instance, I really doubt any type of if-statement shenanigans are going to change much, if anything.

Comment: Option 1 is literally only 2 lines of IL shorter. In the end, they both do the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var pen = highlight ? highlightPen : Pens.Red;


static readonly Pen highlightPen = new Pen(Color.Red, 3.0f);
```

Comment: +1, creating the pen once will probably save much more than the if statement shenanigans

Comment: @Blorgbeard I doubt "save much more [time]". Creating objects is a well-optimized case [esp. when short-lived] .. on the other hand, it does given a semantic name to the highlight color in this case (the same could be argued for a `regularPen` variable/"constant"), which is why I gave a +1.

Answer (score 2):

There is no issue with "performance" here: if a performance issue is *suspected* then *benchmark, benchmark, benchmark* (in a *real usage scenario*) and see.

In any case, my preference is:

```
var pen = highlight
  ? new Pen(Color.Red, 3.0f)
  : Pens.Red;
```

But out of the two above, *I prefer the one **without** the default value*, but not for "performance": I do so because then the C# compiler can then be relied upon to ensure that at least *one* of the value-setting paths is executed (or it will throw a compilation error about the use of an unassigned local variable).

(And yes, while this same holds true for the case *with* an initial value assigned, it breaks down for more complex situations where it is desirable to ensure that *one* of the paths of execution actually executes. Thus I choose consistency, where practical.)

Happy coding!

Comment: In benchmarking this, I would like to compare your answer and both of my other options, How would I go about that?

Comment: @John First, start with a micro-benchmark (keyword); this will given an indication to see if it needs to be explored further. Often times one-off benchmarks use `Stopwatch`; make sure to warm-up the JIT and run for a significant number of times. If the micro-benchmark shows "no disparity" then you're done. Otherwise, expand the micro-benchmark to include the actual usage context .. also, in simple cases like this, looking at the compiler-generated MSIL can reveal the instruction differences (and I hope someone posts such) .. in any case, performance is not a concern/reason to choose one above.

Comment: (Consider, that *even if* a micro-benchmark shows a 50% faster run, but the code tested runs for 0.00001% of the total time the full code takes to executes, the 50% can [almost always] be ignored. I like EQUATEC *for full-program execution time profiling*, but it is not suited for micros.)